# trouble with if statement and the > operator

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to write an if statement and i'm having trouble with my variables. it states operator > can not be applied to type int and string. code located below. both variables are displaying a int.

```
if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > "0")
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing.ToString(); }));
    callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
else if (e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable > "0")
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString(); }));
    callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}
else
{
    callsWaitingData.Text = "0";
    callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing to a string representation of 0, rather than the number 0?

Comment: `if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > "0")` should be changed to `if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 0)`. And so the all if block should be changed this way.

Comment: InQueueInRing is an Int, "0" is a string. For C#, this is not a negotiable difference and it doesn't try to conform to your assumptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error couldn't really get much more descriptive.

> operator > can not be applied to type int and string

```
if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > "0")
                 int -----^          ^--- string
```

Change it to

```
if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 0)
```

Then both sides of the boolean logic is an int.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. simple as it may be. appreciate it.

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 you're most welcome. Simple as it may be once its explained, understanding error messages is an art that you learn with experience. We've all made similar mistakes at some point.

Comment: Any Chance you know why the colors are not changing in the if statement lol?  it works except for the colors

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 2 problems with that. 1) I dont know WPF hardly at all. 2) There is not enough information in your question to answer that. You should ask a new question, make sure you give enough detail (a [mcve]) for people to answer it